# Failure to find dependencies when configuring Maven for multiple modules with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have been implementing an application using Spring Boot with the following Maven hierarchy.

- pom.xml

  - pom.xml [core module]
  - pom.xml [batch module]

The idea behind that structure is as follows: The root pom contains only common libraries, the core pom specifies to package as jar file, and the batch pom use the core for computing some specific tasks. (I have put my pom.xml of those files in the end, too.)

However, when I execute my batch module using the following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I got the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project batch-owl: 
>       Could not resolve dependencies for project io.github.xlives:batch-owl:jar:0.1.0:
>       Failure to find io.github.xlives:core:jar:0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>       resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1][ERROR]

**Parent pom.xml**

```
... 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.github.xlives</groupId>
<artifactId>jSimPi</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>batch-owl</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.semanticweb.owl.owlapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
... End
```

**Core pom.xml**

```
...
<parent>
    <artifactId>jSimPi</artifactId>
    <groupId>io.github.xlives</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
... End
```

**Batch pom.xml**

```
...
<parent>
    <artifactId>jSimPi</artifactId>
    <groupId>io.github.xlives</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>batch-owl</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.xlives</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
... End
```

I am still practicing Maven. Please tell me if you have any concerns on my code.

Thanks :

Comment: Try running a `mvn clean install` before running `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: If `mvn clean install` doesn't work for you, try to delete problematic jar on your local maven repository.

Comment: thank you. solved by running `mvn clean install` before running `mvn spring-boot:run`